# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection An error occurred using the connection to database in staging server

Tags: sql-server, iis, .net-6.0

I have problem in the server for connecting the API to SQL Server.

This application I deploy with IIS on Windows server. On my local machine, it's working fine.

My environment is .NET 6. I use this application for doing the API.

I set my configuration for SQL is

```
Server=<server>;Database=<dbname>;User Id=<user>;Password=<pass>;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

When I'm running the API URL, I get an HTTP 500 internal server error.

The message error from the Event Viewer is

> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection An error occurred using the connection to database ' [dbname] ' on server ' [server] '.
> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Login API'.
> At Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

As you can see, I have already created SQL Server credentials `sa` and `user`. Both accounts can login from the SSMS and execute code/query. I also already granted table to them. I have restarted the SQL Server, and also restarted IIS.

Please help me...

PS: I have tried function that only return string, it works. That mean the application only error when connecting to SQL Server.

Comment: It looks like you haven't added the `IIS APPPOOL\Login API` user to SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK how to add the user of IIS APPPOOL\Login API ? I have update the connection string on the web.config... it still error... 


System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)

Comment: Can I suggest googling for how to add a new login/user to SQL Server (that how I do it every time I need to do it). The normal way you run a .NET site requires that the app pool for your site is added as a user to SQL Server. Because you have `Trusted_Connection=True` which means use the windows login. If you really want to use your username/password then set `Trusted_Connection=False` but I highly recommend not doing that. You should not be passing your SA password around.

Comment: Why do you have both `Trusted_Connection=True;` and `User Id=<user>;Password=<pass>;`? The former is trying to use Windows Authentication (which is why it's picking up the `IIS APPPOOL\Login API` account), the latter uses SQL Login authentication with a particular username and password combination. As Dale said, do not use the `sa` account for this - if your .config file gets compromised then the `sa` credentials will grant full control of your SQL Server.

Comment: I see, I have create new instances of SQL Server for this. I'll also create other than `sa` credential.

Answer (score 0):

you can try instead of database, `Initial Catalog=DBNAME`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34393661)

Comment: I just saw something that possibly can work and I was trying to help. I had to change database = to intial catalog on a mvc project and it worked